# How to resolve conflicts with multiple versions of the same dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've marked my dependencies to be 24.2.1 in app/build gradle file, but when i run " gradlw app:dependencies" it shows 25.1.0 as resolved.not sure how this happening as i haven't add any dependency with 25.1.0 ?is there any way i can find which library pulling the latest

```
  gradlw app:dependencies
    -- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1 -> 25.1.0
       +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
       +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0
```

In Android Studio [image]

Comment: Probably you are using some other libraries which are pulling in the 25.1.0 version

Comment: is there any way i can find which library doing that

Comment: Use this command: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view_the_dependency_tree to check your dependency tree

Comment: im using the gradlw app:dependencies command see the out put, but not sure how can i find out from that result which pulling the latest

Comment: What you have posted is the full output of `gradlw app:dependencies`? If not, find other places where `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` is mentioned.

Comment: Use this command (for Windows) : `./gradlew app:dependencies` then scroll up until you see the dependency tree in the terminal

Comment: so basically i need to see the library "com.android.support:XXX:25.1.0" with out the this symbol "->"

Comment: You have to find `com.android.support:XXX:25.1.0` as requested dependency from your libraries. (they start from the second column of +---)

Comment: @MatPag Thanks found it, followed exactly your steps https://github.com/robohorse/pagerbullet/blob/master/build.gradle this library pulling the 25.1.0 if you please add your steps as answer

Comment: @Sam i've added a more detailed answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Mat.Hope this will help to someone else

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When this happen it's because another library you are using is pulling in other versions of the same dependencies.

You need to figure out your dependency tree with the command

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

to execute in the Android Studio terminal.

Then you need to scroll up the terminal window until you find the dependencies tree, check for some nested dependency coming from thirdy party libraries like in the example image below.

[image]

When you have found a version conflict between the third party dependency and the same dependency you declared in your buid.gradle you can exclude the pulled library and force the library to use your version:

For your problem with the support-library, you could proceed in this way:

```
compile ("com.example.libwithconfictdependency:library:1.0.0") {
    //this to exclude specific modules
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    //or this to exclude every modules of the same package
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

The problems in this case are:

> 1. The library could not work because the dependency you overrided manually are not compatible with the library code
> 2. You need to provide all the necessary dependencies in your build.gradle

That's up to you decide how to proceed about this.